# I filled a shulker box of max books and put it in a chest and broke the server. It said that I went over the protocol

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was being dumb and tested putting in shulker boxes full of max books into a chest and it crashed the server. It said I went too many items over the protocol or something. It's a very good server really can't have to delete it. I have WorldEdit but I can't find a replace command for certain coordinates at all. I have no clue what to do. Please help.

Comment: If the box didn't save, then presumably the books are still wherever they were from the previous save.

Comment: What do you mean by if the box didn't save? It's still in the world.

Comment: You took books then put them in the box, right? It seems to me, that the problem is "Too many books in the box"? ... Spawn more chests and move the books into separate locations, maybe? ... Or delete some books?

Comment: NBT editing should be the solution, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I heard of this problem being used a lot on 2B2T to get players "book banned". It basically happens when a player has too many packets or data on them, and they can't join back in as they get kicked immediately. I believe the only way to get you "un-book banned" is by having an admin wipe your inventory to get rid of the shulker box. And if you're an admin yourself and nobody else has admin privileges on your server, then there's probably some other way for your inventory data to get wiped.

Comment: Ok. So instead of someones inventory it's a chest. It's a chest in the world filled with shulker boxes. It's not in my inventory.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure how to deal with that then. I honestly thought that it only affected inventories. Is everyone on your server crashed, or only you? If it's only you, then prehaps someone else can break the chest, and wait for the shulker box item to despawn, or burn it with a lava bucket?

Comment: Everyone is crashing not just me.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not sure that I can help past that. Prehaps someone else may know what to do with this situation.